# Which was the first set / minifig with two faces to choose from?

Tags: minifigures, history

Some of my minifigs (like Iron Man, and Bilbo Baggins, and Harry Potter) have two different faces to show different emotions (usually something happy and something unhappy or upset or angry). How long have they been doing that? What was the first minifig to have 2 different faces to choose from?

Comment: Lego studios - 2002, like the crazy scientist or the guy in the vampire set...

Answer (score 8):

A quick search on Bricklink gives the following results:

Catalog: Parts: Minifig, Head: Search Results for dual sided

- Unknown year (41)
- 2001 (1)
- 2002 (10)
- 2005 (4)
- 2006 (7)
- 2007 (4)
- 2008 (4)
- 2009 (18)
- 2010 (27)
- 2011 (43)
- 2012 (86)
- 2013 (90)
- 335 Total Parts (View All)

This search was caried out at [http://www.bricklink.com](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&q=dual%20sided&catLike=W&catType=P&catID=238&v=1)

Assuming that the Bricklink data are complete and correct, there are 41 double sided heads without a known release date, and the trend seems to have started in 2001 with this one:

- [Minifig, Head Dual Sided HP Quirrell / Voldemort Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3626bpx118)

Comment: Except that even that head was included in sets as early as 1993 according to bricklink...

Comment: @gev - fixed the link.

Comment: +1, but I'm going to say (arbitrarily perhaps) that Quirrell / Voldemort doesn't count, because it's not two different faces / emotions of the same person, it's a head that actually has two faces (canonically even). I'll update my question to make this more clear.

Comment: I have reviewed the answers given, and have looked at Bricklink again to check every set that every yellow-skinned minifigure head came in.

Comment: I have reviewed the answers given, and have looked at Bricklink again to check every set that every yellow-skinned double-sided minifigure head came in.  (I ignored all non-yellow as they must have been made later.)   The earliest if could find (and that I can remember buying) that match the emotions criterion are: 3626bpx116 and 3626bpx117 from 'Spiderman' and 'Studios' 2002/2003

Answer (score 1):

I was a child with wealthy parents during the early 90's and thus own almost every set released during that period. apart from the harry potter one mentioned, the first that showed the same face with different emotion I remember getting was a small set that included a new skeleton face as well as a mummy. This Mummy was double sided with one face asleep, and one face awake.